# Transfers on Greyhound

Tags: tickets, buses, greyhound

One of the trips on Greyhound says there are 3 transfers. Does that mean I have to get off the bus and switch to a different bus 3 times?

Comment: Probably, but it's hard to say without information about the route you're referring to

Comment: What did Greyhound say when you asked them?